# UINavigationController displaying the wrong view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to implement a basic `UINavigationController` and I'm running into an issue with the navigation controller displaying a wrong view.

I started by creating a `Window Based Application` in `Xcode 4` that gave me the following files:`spellingAppDelegate.h`, `spellingAppDelegate.m` and `MainWindows.xib`.  I then added a new `UIViewController` subclass and call it `gameViewController`.

The following is my code for `myAppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface spellingAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

the following is my myAppDelegate.m

```
#import "spellingAppDelegate.h"
#import "gameViewController.h"
#import "resultViewController.h"

@implementation spellingAppDelegate

@synthesize window = window;
@synthesize navigationController = navigationController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // create the MyView controller instance:
    gameViewController *controller = [[gameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameViewController" bundle:nil];

    // set the title that appears in the navigation bar:
    [controller.navigationItem setTitle:@"Main View"];

    // create the Navigation Controller instance:
    UINavigationController *newnav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    // set the navController property:
    [self setNavigationController:newnav];

    // release both controllers:
    [newnav release];
    [controller release];

    // add the Navigation Controller's view to the window:
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    return YES;
}
```

I was under the impression that if i run the above code, the app will start with gameViewController.xib.  However, its displaying MainWindow.xib.  I know I'm probably miss something basic but I can't figure out what I did wrong.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
   [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do it in this way it will work

```
demoViewController *controller = [[demoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"demoViewController" bundle:nil];

// set the title that appears in the navigation bar:
[controller.navigationItem setTitle:@"Main View"];

// create the Navigation Controller instance:
UINavigationController *newnav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

// set the navController property:
//   [self setNavigationController:newnav];

[self.window addSubview:newnav.view];

// release both controllers:
[newnav release];
[controller release];
```

Comment: i couldn't get your code to work as is.  however if i remove the comment for [self setNavigationController:newnav];  it works.

Answer (score 1):

The application's window is defined in a nib file. Typically, this nib is `MainWindow.xib`, although you can change it by editing your application's `info.plist` file.

You can place a reference to the view controller you want to load at startup in this nib (see the view-based application template), or you can use the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in the application delegate to the same effect.

On iOS 4.0 and later I would use the `UIWindow` property `rootViewController` to add the view controller.  For example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    AViewController * aViewController = [[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = aViewController;
    [aViewController release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```